# Unable to start World Wide Web Publishing service

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6

I recently rebooted my Win2003 server and World Wide Web Publishing service did not start back up.  I get the following error in the System Event log when I try to start manually:

```
Source: Service Control Manager
Event ID: 7024
Description:
The World Wide Web Publishing Service service terminated with service-specific error 2147746132 (0x80040154).
```

Another strange thing I noticed while troubleshooting:  When I view the properties of both IIS Admin Service and World Wide Web Publishing Service, I get an `Interface: Class not registered.` error and all the depedencies are blank (I would expect to see RPC, HTTP, etc. here).

Has anyone experienced this behavior before?